# Using dropDownList with listData() in yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

How do I use dropDownList with listData() to select from integers 1, 2, 3 in yii. I doing it in following way but it is not working.

```
public static function getaccessLevel()
{
    $models[] = array(1 => '1', 2=> '2', 3=> '3');
    return CHtml::listData($models, '1', '2', '3');
}
echo $form->dropDownList($user,'timezone', $user->getaccessLevel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function getaccessLevel()
{
    return array(1 => '1', 2=> '2', 3=> '3');
}

echo $form->dropDownList($user,'timezone', $user->getaccessLevel());
```

Comment: But with this method I am not able to save the selected value.

Comment: I don't understand.. the 'getaccessLevel()' only return the array. The $form->dropDownList() it's sent on 'submit' form, then it's saved on the pertinent model.